# Android Date Parsing error

Tags: android, date, parsing

I am developing in an Android app, in that I facing error in date parsing.

> ava.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2017-02-10T00:00:00.000Z"

Code:

```
String dt="2017-02-24T12:00:00.000Z";

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ");
    try{
        Date dateFrom=format.parse(dt);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String dt = "2017-02-24T12:00:00.000Z";

SimpleDateFormat mainformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.getDefault());

try {
     Date dateFrom = mainformat.parse(dt);
} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is a exact solution for your problem.The problem is that the instance of simple date format is not right.Try this. Ask if you have anu query.

Comment: Welcome. Enjoy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 1 too many zero's at the end it should be "2017-02-24T12:00:00.00Z"

Comment: I got it working when i tried this "new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");"

Comment: This was almost spot-on. ss = seconds. SSS = milliseconds. I made similar.